# Constructor implícito y explicito

Tags: java

hola buenas quisiera saber como se hace en java un constructor implícito
y un constructor explicito .
aquí le dejo nose si hice bien el constructor implícito bien  alguien que me explique por favor.

```
//
public class Persona {
String nombre;
byte edad;
String sexo;
double salario;

//contructor implicito
public Persona(){
    nombre = "";
    edad = 0;
    sexo="";
    salario= 0 ;

}

//en la clase principal

public class Uso_Persona {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Persona oPersona=new Persona();
    oPersona.nombre="Jose Luis";

    System.out.println(oPersona.nombre);
}

}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Hacer algo, de ***forma explícita***, implica una intervención activa en un proceso, la ***forma implícita*** es aquella que no requiere intervención por nuestra parte o la del programa, supone un comportamiento automático o por defecto.

Aplicado a los constructores de clase, el implícito es aquel que asigna los valores por defecto que tendrán las propiedades si no se utiliza otro constructor. El constructor explícito requiere una "intervención", algo algo o alguien asigna unos valores determinados a esas propiedades en el momento de instanciar la clase que no tienen porqué ser los valores por defecto. Se usa un constructor que asigna a las propiedades unos valores determinados que pueden ser diferentes para cada objeto que se instancia.

Ejemplo:

```
class Foo {

    private char grupo;
    private int edad;

    /**
     * Constructor implícito
     *
     */
    Foo() {
        grupo = 'A';
        edad  = 16;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor explícito
     *
     */
    Foo(grupo, edad) 
    {

        this.grupo = grupo;
        this.edad  = edad;
    }

} //class
```

Y a la hora de instanciar objetos de la clase:

```
Foo a = new Foo();        //Usa el constructor implícito
Foo b = new Foo('A', 15); //Usa el constructor explícito
```